# JS How to make a reduce to sum a index of a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I need help to learn how to make a reduce to a array like this:

```
a=[ ["ww","fsf",40],["ww","fsf",30],["ww","fsf",10]]
```

I want to learn how to sum the 40+30+10 using the method reduce. I know how to do it if the array was [40,30,10]. 
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.reduce` applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value:

```
a.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

Your values will be arrays:

```
["ww","fsf",40]
["ww","fsf",30]
["ww","fsf",10]
```

So you can use:

```
a.reduce(function(sum, value) {
  return sum + value[2];
}, 0);
```

Or using ES6 new [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions):

```
 a.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value[2], 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very usefull.

Comment: You're missing the initial value in the arrow function example.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for notifying me :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
a.reduce((sum, row) => sum + row[row.length - 1], 0)
```

Comment: Can you explain the => ? Can you write the same using the syntax function(){} inside the reduce? Thank you.